# How to load and read XML documents

Tags: c#, xml, document

I'm using NET 2.0 WinForms for my C# application. Previously I used .NET 4.0 and used the following code to read an XML document:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(spath);
foreach (XElement xe in doc.Elements("Snippets").Elements("Snippet"))
{
    string sName = (string)xe.Attribute("name");
    string sCode = xe.Element("SnippetCode").Value;
    listBox1.Items.Add(snippetName);
    snippets.Add(sCode);
}
```

However, I don't know how to get the attribute and element value with .NET 2.0. Can anyone help me? I know I have to use XMLDocument but I don't know anything beyond loading an XML document in that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Untested code, but I think you get the idea:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(spath);
        foreach (XmlElement xe in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Snippets/Snippet"))
        {
            string sName = xe.Attributes["name"].Value;
            string sCode = xe.SelectSingleNode("/SnippetCode").InnerText;
            listBox1.Items.Add(snippetName);
            snippets.Add(sCode);
        }
```

Comment: You forgot the "/" before the Snippets/Snippet string, but apart from that, it's perfect.

Comment: Actually since he used DocumentElement, he doesn't need the starting slash. It's assumed.

Comment: Apparently it isn't assumed because his code wasn't working correctly without it.